# Codeigniter code required for image upload in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need full code , where i could upload full image size in the database (not only image path but whole image size). Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not a free code service. Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

To upload Images or files you use following code to your controller as

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Refferecne:[Codeigniter Files upload guideline](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

How ever if you want to upload image using Ajax then please don't forget to knock then i will give entire codes blocks.

Thank you!

Comment: Codeigniter doc's now located here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs please use links from here not ellislab as they are out dated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert the image into bytes and save it on MYSQL database?
If yes, then try this code

```
<?php
$filename = "image.png";
$file = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);
?>
```